# Nested MDX component

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby

I have a componet which used in mdx files
The problem is that the content in the componet is rendered as text but I want to render them as mdx.
This is how mdx file look likes:

```
---
title: Topic 1
---
<Notice> Notice **Two** with link [link](https://angular.io/) </Notice>

outside look: Notice **Two** with link [link](https://angular.io/)
```

And this is the `Notice` component

```
import React from "react";

const Notice = ({ children, type }: { children: any; type?: string }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "2px solid dodgerblue" }}>
      <p>{type}</p>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Notice;
```

And also this is the code of root file:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx";
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react"

import Notice from './notice/notice';


export default function ({ docName, title, body, slug }) {
  const shortcodes = {Notice};
  return (
    <div style={gridWrapper}>
      <article>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <div>
          <MDXProvider components={shortcodes}>
              <MDXRenderer>{body}</MDXRenderer>
          </MDXProvider>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you clarify "The problem is that the content in the componet is rendered as text" what component and text do you mean (in your example)?

Comment: `<Notice> Notice **Two** with link [link](https://angular.io/) </Notice>` this part in the mdx file should be rendered as a link and a bold text right? but it shown as simple text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `</Notice>` this part in the mdx file should be rendered as a link and
> a bold text right?

It doesn't unless you add an MDX Renderer or a markdown parser (like [`markdown-to-jsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx)) to parse the markdown syntax into HTML.

In the end, what you are wrapping inside `Notice` is a plain text that is rendered using the `Notice`'s component JSX structure, where the `children` is rendered as-is (`{children}`).

That said, you can try using the `MDXRenderer` in your `Notice` component like:

```
import React from "react";
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"

const Notice = ({ children, type }: { children: any; type?: string }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "2px solid dodgerblue" }}>
      <p>{type}</p>
      <MDXRenderer>{children}</MDXRenderer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Notice;
```

I'm not sure how will behave the code nesting `MDXRenderer`, that's why I suggested the `markdown-to-jsx` solution, which will result in a very similar scenario like:

```
import React from "react";
import Markdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';

const Notice = ({ children, type }: { children: any; type?: string }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "2px solid dodgerblue" }}>
      <p>{type}</p>
      <Markdown>{children}</Markdown>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Notice;
```